# Borel Measure questions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, lp-spaces

I'm little bit confused about Borel measure. What are the check to do for a Borel measure identification? Is true that these functions defined on every Borel set $F \in 2^R$ are Borel?

1) $\mu(F) := \sup F - \inf F$

2) $\mu(F) = 0$ if F countable, $+\infty$ if not

3) $\mu(F) = 0$ if $x \in F$, $\mu(F) = 1$ if not

4) $\mu(F) = $$\int_{F}^{} e^x dx$

Here my ideas for those questions

1) I can define $F=[a,b)$ and since the sup of F is not defined $\rightarrow$ False

2) According to $\sigma$-algebra measure definition, $\mu(\emptyset)=0$, but here the measure is 0 even if it's not empty $\rightarrow$ False

3) It's like the "inverse" of the Dirac measure, or an inverse of the characteristic function, but other than these motivation I can't figure out other stuff  $\rightarrow$ True

4) $\mu(F) = $$\int_{F}^{} e^x dx = C\int_{B_r(0)}^{} {\chi}_F \rho^2 e^\rho d\rho$ this integral is finite $\rightarrow$ True

I need more structure on the subject, I'm afraid I'm missing huge chunks of proofs

Answer (score 1):

There are many mistakes in your arguments. '$\sup F$ not defined' is not an argument for 1). If $A$ is the set of all rational numbers in $(0,)$ and $B$ is the set of all irrational numbers in $(0,)$ then $\mu (A)=1, \mu(B)=1$ and $\mu (A \cup B)=1$. Since $A$ and $B$ are disjoint this contraducts the definition of a measure. So the answer to 1) is NO.

There is no requirement that the measure of a non-empty set is not zero.The answer to 2) is YES and I leave it to you to verify that this $\mu$ is indeed countable additive. [Let me know if you need help with this].

In 3) $\mu (\emptyset) =1$ which is not permissible, so the answer is NO.

in 4) $\mu$ is a Borel measure and this follows by standard measure theoretic arguments.

Comment: For 2) I know that $R=I \cup Q$ (Irrational and Rational), so I can apply the measure map $\mu(R)=\mu(I)+\mu(Q)$, so it is additive. Is this the correct argument for this point?

Comment: No. Just giving an example where the measures ad up does not prove additivity.

Comment: Maybe: I sum a countable number of set that with that measure are infinite, but are countable? I have to think about if it's not this

Comment: Let $A$ be the union of disjoint Borel sets $A_n$. Consider two cases: 1) each $A_n$ is countable. 2) One of the $A_n$'s is not countable. In case 1) observe that $A$ is countable. Now verify that $\mu (A)=\sum \mu(A_n)$ in both cases.